# CodeClimate and Travis configuration ignoring commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci, code-climate

I'm trying to setup Travis and CodeClimate integration but after setting test coverage configuration, my build started to fail.

My `.travis.yml` file contains something like

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.5.0
branches:
  only:
  - master
services:
  - postgresql
env: 
  - RAILS_ENV=test
  global:
    - DB=postgresql
    - CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID=<my_cc_id>
bundler_args: --without production
script: 
  - bundle exec rake db:schema:load
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rake spec
before_script:
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database my_db_test;' -U postgres
  - curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > ./test_reporter
  - chmod +x ./test_reporter
  - ./test_reporter before-build RAILS_ENV=test
after_script:
  - ./test_reporter after-build --exit-code $TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT
```

Before the test coverage integration, the output displayed these lines, just after `bundle install`

```
$ psql -c 'create database my_db_test;' -U postgres
$ cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
```

but after, the output displays this line after `bundle install`

```
$ bundle exec rake
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby -I/home/travis/build/username/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib:/home/travis/build/username/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rspec-support-3.7.1/lib /home/travis/build/username/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
```

the `bundle exec rake` runs before my command to overwrite `database.yml` and breaks the build.

Can someone help me understand what is this command and why is he beeing called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue, the failures was being caused by my var configuration. The right way to config them is:

```
env: 
  global:
    - RAILS_ENV=test
    - DB=postgresql
    - CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID=<my_cc_id>
```